# Which movie holds the record for using the highest number of extras in a scene?

Tags: first-appearance

Often they make use of extras in a movie scene typically for depicting a crowd, a stadium filled with people, a rally, a procession etc.

I want to know that in which movie the highest number of extras were used for filming a scene.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [record](http://web.archive.org/web/20051126142323/http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/content_pages/record.asp?recordid=50642) for most extras is with 1982 classic [Gandhi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083987/), which used over 300,000 extras for the funeral scene.

IMDb Trivia snippet:

> 300,000 extras appeared in the funeral sequence. About 200,000 were
>   volunteers and 94,560 were paid a small fee (under contract). The
>   sequence was filmed on 31st Jan 1981, the 33rd anniversary of Mohandas
>   K. Gandhi's funeral. 11 crews shot over 20,000 feet of film, which was
>   pared down to 125 seconds in the final release.

Comment: The most wasted opportunity in the history of cinema.

Comment: @user207421 why?