# How are large crowds filmed?

Tags: film-techniques

I've often been curious how really large crowds in movies / TV programs are filmed. e.g. in a stadium at a big football match or something, I'm guessing they don't simply hire tens of thousands of extras! (Or maybe they do? But I'm pretty sure I've seen this even in relatively low-budget works).

Since this predates CGI, a non-CGI answer would be good!

If it's a kind of copy-and-paste going on, it would be good to have an example so to try and spot the repetition...

Comment: Either that or they just film from a platform down on the crowd with a good resolution cmera.

Answer (score -2):

There are two options on how this can be done. Firstly, that can use special editing like AI to add lots of people onto the screen, without there actually being in there (this is how they did it in The Hunger Games in the interviews).

Or, they can actually get thousands of people in real life, however this would not be very practical, so 99% of the time they use the first option I previously suggested.

Comment: not really. check the answer in [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9874/how-do-they-make-a-huge-crowd-in-a-movie)

Comment: Also, the OP specifically requested NON-CGI answers,